# Math question: How know section number on a list

Tags: math

Imagine I have this list, that is divided by 3

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Now, I have 9 items, grouped in 3 sections.

My question is how know in which section is 6 (ie: 6 belong to section 2, 2 to section 1, 9 to section 3)

Comment: could you please explain what a section is? In your stream of 1 to 9 I don't see anything that keeps groups of numbers apart.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm...... `section = ((item-1) / 3) + 1`

Answer (score 2):

`section = ceiling (n / 3)`

For example,

`ceiling (4 / 3) = ceiling ( 1.33 ) = 2`

Answer (score 2):

For a list of items divided into sections of size `n`, the section `s` of an item `i` is given by:

```
s = (i + (n-1)) / n,
```

where the `/` is integer division.

So, for your example, item 6 gives `(6 + (3-1))/3 = (6+2)/3 = 8/3 = 2`.

This applies to many other things as well - I encountered it as "How many nodes do I need to request on a cluster with `n` CPUs per node?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but give this a try:

```
floor((itemNumber - 1)/numberOfGroups) + 1
```